# Cuadro con html para copiar

Tags: javascript, html

me gustaria crear algo así, un cuadro con html dentro para que el usuario al pulsar el boton se copie el codigo en el portapapeles.

[image: vasc]

Gracias

Comment: Puedes indicar mas informacion sobre lo que deseas obtener en el contexto de lo que tienes? codigo actual que has intentado, que parte es la que deseas ayuda (en el cuadro de codigo, el boton de copia , ambos?)

Comment: Deseo reproducir exactamente lo de la imagen, con la funcion de copiar al portapapeles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementar el copiado a portapapeles es algo sencillo, puedes guiarte por [esta referencia](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp).

El implementar un componente de bloque de codigo formateado, con lineas y un boton de copia al portapapeles a la vez puede ser mas complicado y llevar mucho tiempo. Pero puedes comenar basandote en alguna implementacion segun las librerias de javascript/css que estes ocupando.

De otro modo puedes usar [esta implementacion en javascript/css](https://css-tricks.com/web-component-for-a-code-block/) como se demuestra en este ejemplo: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/povpLOp

Comment: Genial! era justo lo que quería. Gracias :D

Comment: Que buena noticia, si te pareció util y resuelve tu problema recuerda que puedes marcar las respuestas utiles  para indicar que ya fue resuelta. Si te quedan mas dudas comenta lo que quieras aclarar.